# SSRS - Show field in header but only when displaying first page of records for a group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS report where I have a Row Group and then the Groups details.

The Row Group is grouped on Customer number. The Group Details contain order details

My report has 10 unique customer numbers. Some customers have multiple pages of orders, some only have 1 page of orders in the SSRS report.

I need the Customer number to only show up in the header if the report is on the first page (or first record) of orders for a particular Customer number.

In other words,  I need to show a field in the header but only when displaying first page of records for a group.

So if a customer has 10 pages of orders in my ssrs report, I only want his customer number to show up in the header on page 1 of his orders, the other 9 pages should not show his customer number.

We would not see another Customer number on the SSRS report until the next (different) customer number record appears which will again only be visible on the first page of it's orders and so on...

How can I achieve this? Is it possible?

Update:

I am going to try to achieve what I need by using the rownumber function. If it's currently on row number 1 then show the Customer Number, if its not on row number 1 then don't show it in the tablix. I'll make the textbox hidden but I'll call it from the Header textbox.

I just need the rownumber to reset to 1 everytime it switches to a new customer...

I'll try it out and post back if it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a quick fix for now but I will need to find a better more stable solution.

I just put the below Expression in a textbox and it got me what I wanted.

```
=IIF(RowNumber("CustomerNumber") < 34, "Text you want to display goes here", "")
```

I saw that max number of lines per page for my report was 33 for the "CustomerNumber" row group. So the expressions checks if the row count is < 34 then you are still on the first page so go ahead and show the customer number or whatever text you decide...

This will break if the layout of the report is modified to where more than 34 lines can fit on a page for example which is why I see it only as a temporary solution (just to get the report out).

Answer (score 0):

`=ReportItems!CustomerNumber.Value = First(Fields!CustomerNumber.Value)`

ReportItems![fieldname].value returns the value in the first textbox of that name *on the page* and then you compare that to the first value in the group.